# How to get MR number in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I get the MR number in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which is used in the Gitlab CI pipeline?

I am using Gitlab integrated CI pipeline. I tried to look into the predefined variables section but there isn't anything that gives me the MR number?
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: There are [predefined variables for merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines). In your case, probably `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID`

Comment: `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` does not give me any number! Its blank

Comment: You need to be running a `merge_request` pipeline. ie, add `rules: - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'` or `only: - merge_request` to your job.

Comment: the variable is only filed in case of `merge_request` pipeline

Comment: Strange. This is running from an MR which is on the MR wall for review. There are still clauses applicable? I cant just simply get the MR number from inside the .yml file? But, anyways I then understand the MR number is not straight-forward to get.

Comment: Thanks @Rekovni, you save my day! After add "only: - merge_request", I can get merge request iid !